# Find and replace the entire line of the source file

Tags: command-line, text-processing, awk

I am working on a batch script which will call the .awk file to execute the find and replace.

1. batch file script.cmd file -->

   ```
   @gawk -f "%Modify.awk%" "%Temp.csv%" < "%Source.csv%" > "%Output.csv%".
   ```
2. Temp.csv contains,

   ```
   | UID | Name | Num | Loc | Addr | Str
   |95 | Bank| Amal| | Che| | KKKK
   ```
3. Source contains

   ```
   | UID | Name | Num | Loc | Addr | Str
   |34 | Per | ffff | hhhh | kkkk | llll | KKKK
   |95 | Bank| ffff | hhhh | XXXX | YYYY | LLLL
   |100 | Hel | Join | JJJJ | HHHH
   ```

After executing batch script i want to have the output as below(i.e) Temp file value should be replaced in source.

Output:

```
| UID | Name | Num | Loc | Addr | Str
|34 | Per | ffff | hhhh | kkkk | llll | KKKK
|95 | Bank| Amal| | Che| | KKKK
|100 | Hel | Join | JJJJ | HHHH
```

Modify.awk:

```
BEGIN{
#
# Define field separator
#
  FS="\t";
  OFS="\t";
}
{
  /^95/
    {
     getline 
     print $1
     }
}
END{
#  print "NReject: ",NReject," on a total of: ",NR-1;
}
```

NOTE: The Temp & Source file is .csv file fields separated with Tab value

Comment: This is an awk script

Answer (score 1):

I would create a sed script to replace your temp file because sed is designed for this task.  Awk is better at other things.

eg: create a file `rep.sed` with the replacement commands, to find and replace the lines starting with 95 you could use:

```
s/^|95.*/|95 | Bank| Amal| | Che| | KKKK/g
```

then run sed on your source

```
sed -f rep.sed sourcefile
```

Pipe the output to a new file when it is working

```
sed -f rep.sed sourcefile > updatedsourcefile
```

adding other lines to rep.sed will perform all replacements in one pass

```
s/^|95.*/|95 | Bank| Amal| | Che| | KKKK/g
s/^|100.*/|100 | Bank| Amal| | Che| | LLLL/g
```